# Access protobuf field name dynamically with scala

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I am new to Scala. Writing my first application.

I have defined my proto file with fields email_id and phone_number which is request definition for grpc call

I can access values by dot operator like params.emailId

Now what I am trying to do is I have one array of mandatory fields. I want to check the values for those fields defined in an array with input request parameters.

How can i access this params.{field name from array} to check for not empty values.

Getting error for below code with :

```
  val mandatoryFields = Array("emailId","phoneNumber")

  println(params.emailId) //works
  for (fields <- mandatoryFields) {
    println(fields)
    println(params.fields) // getting error
  }
```

It has function 'in.getFieldByNumber()' where you can fetch value by index location, is there any function available like getFieldByName() or something like that.

Comment: See if this helps you https://scalapb.github.io/generated-code.html

Comment: Can you show class of `params`?

Comment: my proto message for params is :   `message Request{
    string email_id = 1;
    string phone_number = 2;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Although it's been a long from the question date, I don't think it is answerless. Actually, I have one:

Using `toPMessage` method, you'll have your protobuffer case class as an instance of `PMessage` object. Then you could retrieve the `Map[FieldDescriptor, PValue]`. Finding field values by name would be like:

```scala
val fieldDescriptorPValueMap: Map[FieldDescriptor, PValue] = params.toPMessage.value

mandatoryFields.foreach(fieldName=>{
      println(
        fieldDescriptorPValueMap
          .filter(entry => fieldName == entry._1.name)
          .values
          .head.as[String]
      )
})
```